# Saving data for a basic leaderboard?

Tags: java

I know how to save data pretty easily with the printWriter to a txt file etc.

I have a mineSweeper game that saves the name, boardsize, time taken for completion and how many mines were used; the file looks like this:

name

10x10

00:00:01

20

gap

repeat

but trying to get this to be sorted is going to be a very difficult ordeal as none of this data when saved in a file is technically "related.

Are there any ways of saving this data so they are some what related.

I was thinking of saving it in one big long string with break character at the end and between such as

```
 name + "!!" + boardSize + "!!" + time + "!!" + mines + "!?" < as the end break
```

any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Database > XML >>  Serialization or plain text

Comment: JSON will give your data some relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data as xml:

```
<root>
<name>...</name>
<boardsize>...</boardsize>
.
.
.
</root>
```

This way you will be maintain relationship with your data when extracting it back from file

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be sqlLite, it's portable and fairly straight forward to use, Tutorial point have a pretty good example of how to set it up and use it - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

Might also be worth looking into joins if you want to store related data in seperare tables - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, create a `model` of a game session
**define a class** of that a serialize it to lets say **json**

> {name:xoce, size:10x10, time:00:00:01, mines:20}

when this step is ready, append every game result to a Txtfile and if you want to sort, then read the file, deserialize it to a json list and sort the list with the anonymous Comparator so you can play with your best sort criteria

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `Game` class which will contain all the necessary attributes - `name`, `boardSize`, ... - and will implement `Serializable` and  `Comparable<T>` so you can sort it in an array later.

Then you can simply save it to a file using `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
List<Game> gamesList = ...; // I suppose you have a list of games you want to store
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(...);
oos.writeObject(gamesList);
...
```